# Can not retrieving my password from my key chain in iOS 13 Simulator

Tags: objective-c, keychain, ios13, simulator, xcode11

I have saved my password in ios keychain using the below code.

```
 CFErrorRef *err = nil;
SecAccessControlRef sacRef = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(
    kCFAllocatorDefault,
    kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly,
    kSecAccessControlUserPresence,
    err);

 NSDictinary *attributes = @{
    (__bridge id)kSecClass : (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
    (__bridge id)kSecAttrService : KeychainServiceName,
    (__bridge id)kSecValueData : [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
    (__bridge id)kSecUseAuthenticationUI : @NO,
    (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessControl : (__bridge_transfer id)sacRef
};

OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)attributes, nil);
if (status != errSecSuccess) {
    [self resetTouchIDPreference];
}
```

I can be retrieving the password in real iPhone devices and below iOS 13 simulators using the above code. But I can't retrieve the password in the iOS 13(iPhone 11 Pro Max iOS 13)simulator.

when I Remove the `kSecAttrAccessControl` key from the dictionary `attributes` it'll work even also in iOS 13 devices.

My question is

> > why this key is not working in the iOS 13 simulator?. how do you write common code for both device and simulator?

I'm using below code to retrieving the password from the keychain

```
     NSDictionary *query = @{
                    (__bridge id)kSecClass : (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                    (__bridge id)kSecAttrService : KeychainServiceName,
                    (__bridge id)kSecReturnData : @YES,
                    (__bridge id)kSecUseOperationPrompt : @"Your account is just a thumbprint away."
                };

                CFTypeRef dataTypeRef = NULL;
                OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(query), &dataTypeRef);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you set a passcode on a simulator.  You may want to try ```#if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR  kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock, #else kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly, #endif``` (with the precompiled directives on their own line of course) when you create the SecAccessControlRef, so you use different access control parameters on the simulator.

Comment: @CarlLindberg As per now, I'm writing a condition for device and simulator. But there has any alternate solution for this. Thanks.